# primeng css not loading on route change, angular5 app

Tags: angular, primeng

[image]I have create a small app in anuglar5 using prime-ng. The issue I am facing is that when I change route via router.navigate[], the css is not getting applied on new route/component.

But when I directly enter the new route path in browser the css is getting applied and everything is working perfectly.

please help.

EDIT:1- `<p-button label="Start" (onClick)="handleClickAddTest($event)"></p-button>`

Comment: Did you check primeng styles are ready on DOM? You may be loading it correctly but there might be something else overriding it.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Inspect your elements which you expect to be affected by primeng css. Also, on developer tools-Elements tab (Chrome), you can search for primeng css rules.

Comment: No, there is no primeng related css there, but when I refresh the route (F5), it is rendering correctly.

Comment: Where did you put the reference to primeng css? In `.angular-cli` or in `index.html`?

Comment: It looks like Directive is not parsing correctly on route change. Reference is in .angular-cli & also tried styles.css (~/.)

Comment: What directive are you talking about? Can you share some code in your question? It is really hard to help without seeing anything.

Comment: Where did you import primeng `ButtonModule`?